# p5.js: How can I make text appear when my mouse hovers over a different text element in the sketch in processing?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

Here is my code. In this, I want when I HOVER on each country's name, on the bottom left of the screen, I want to make more information about that country (about a paragraph) to appear. The code to make the diameter big and small (pulsing circles) is sourced from somewhere else. I want to be able to hover over each of the country name text and see info on the screen that disappears after I move my cursor from that country's name.

```
let maxDiameter;

let theta;

let img;



preload = () => {
        img = loadImage('1x/map-5.png');
}

setup = () => {

    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    maxDiameter = 45;

    theta = 0;

    background(0);
    ellipseMode();



}

draw = () => {
    background(0);

     fill(255, 0, 0, 255);
    noStroke();

    textSize(20);
    fill(255, 0, 0, 255);

    //United States
    var diam = 10 + sin(theta) * maxDiameter;
    fill(132, 132, 132, 200);
     stroke(132, 132, 132, 200);
    text('United States', 230, 260);
    ellipse(200, 240, diam, diam);


    //Morocco

    fill(0, 255, 0, 200);
    stroke(0, 255, 0, 200);
     text('Morocco', 500, 300);
    ellipse(590, 315, diam, diam);

    //Canada

    fill(253, 100, 1, 200);
    stroke(253, 100, 1, 200);
     text('Canada', 260, 140);
    ellipse(230, 140, diam, diam);

 //Russian Federation


    fill(132, 132, 132, 200);
    stroke(132, 132, 132, 200);
     text('Russian Federation', 1030, 130);
    ellipse(1000, 125, diam, diam);

    //Japan

    fill(255, 0, 0, 200);
    stroke(255, 0, 0, 200);
     text('Japan', 1330, 245);
    ellipse(1295, 245, diam, diam);

    theta += 0.03;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Anushka. It would be a lot of help if you could show us what you have already tried. [Here is an example](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/mouseOver) of how p5 handles mouseovers. Make an effort. And if you get stuck we'll be glad to help you out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to evaluate if the mouse is on the text. The mouse position can be get by [`mouseX`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseX) and [`mouseY`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseY). The height of the text is set by [`textSize`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/textSize) and the width of a text can be get by [`textWidth`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/textWidth). e.g.:

```js
textH = 20 
textSize(textH);
```

```js
text('United States', 230, 260);
textW = textWidth('United States')
if (mouseX > 230 && mouseX < 230+textW && mouseY < 260 && mouseY > 260-textH) {
    text('text', 230, 260+5+textH);
}
```

See the example, where the code is used in  function (`textExpand`):

```js
let maxDiameter;
let theta;

setup = () => {

    createCanvas(1500, 600);
    maxDiameter = 45;

    theta = 0;

    background(0);
    ellipseMode();
}

textExpand = (textMain, textAdd, textX, textY, textH) => {
      textSize(textH);
      text(textMain, textX, textY);
      textW = textWidth(textMain)
      if (mouseX > textX && mouseX < textX+textW && mouseY < textY && mouseY > textY-textH) {
          text(textAdd, textX, textY+5+textH);
      }
}

draw = () => {
    background(0);

     fill(255, 0, 0, 255);
    noStroke();

    textH = 20 
    textSize(textH);
    fill(255, 0, 0, 255);

    //United States
    var diam = 10 + sin(theta) * maxDiameter;
    fill(132, 132, 132, 200);
    stroke(132, 132, 132, 200);
    textExpand('United States', 'test1', 230, 260, 20);
    ellipse(200, 240, diam, diam);


    //Morocco
    fill(0, 255, 0, 200);
    stroke(0, 255, 0, 200);
    textExpand('Morocco', 'test2', 500, 300, 20);
    ellipse(590, 315, diam, diam);

    //Canada

    fill(253, 100, 1, 200);
    stroke(253, 100, 1, 200);
    textExpand('Canada', 'test3', 260, 140, 20);
    ellipse(230, 140, diam, diam);

     //Russian Federation

    fill(132, 132, 132, 200);
    stroke(132, 132, 132, 200);
    textExpand('Russian Federation', 'test4', 1030, 130, 20);
    ellipse(1000, 125, diam, diam);

    //Japan
    fill(255, 0, 0, 200);
    stroke(255, 0, 0, 200);
    textExpand('Japan', 'test5', 1330, 245, 20);
    ellipse(1295, 245, diam, diam);

    theta += 0.03;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is great and works almost just as a want it to. Is there a way I can position the added text at a different custom position?

Comment: @AnushkaJadwani Of course, add some more arguments to `textExpand`